# IPN Post Is Empty, Every Time

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using the IPN example straight from the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/#listener).

I pay to PayPal with no problems, PayPal redirects to my listener with no problems, but is always coming up with an empty $_POST variable. Can anyone see a problem?

```
<?php
   // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification 
   header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 

    // Assign payment notification values to local variables
    $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];

    // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '</pre><hr/>';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
        $req  .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
    }

    // Set up the acknowledgement request headers
    $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                    // HTTP POST request
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);               // Get the acknowledgement response

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification
            // Authentication protocol is complete - OK to process notification contents
            echo 'thanks for the payment, we are processing your request.';
         } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            //Response contains INVALID - reject notification
            echo 'something has gone wrong. please try again.';
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);  // Close the file

?>
```

Result:

```
array(0) {
}
something has gone wrong. please try again.
```

**UPDATED TO ADD BUTTON CODE:**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="H7G2W8WN4XXXXX">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="0.25">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="0.25">

<input type="submit" value="Buy Now"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your button code here ?

Comment: @Eshan it is now included.

Comment: Have you tried using the [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) to send a test request? I just did this myself with a simple 2 line script (return the header and dump $_POST to file) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Actually I was trying to reach to the checkout page but since the button code doesn't have the complete value for business parameters  , I am not able to test

Comment: Use the FireFox `tamperdata` plugin to see what is coming back from the PayPal servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found another document buried on the PayPal site somewhere, with a newer example script. It worked right away, out of the box (as the original one should have).

Here is the link for anyone looking this up: https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not seeing anything is because `var_dump()` is meant to output `$_POST` to the browser.  So when you visit the IPN URL, you are not posting anything to the page, hence nothing in there.  Further, the rest of the script still executes, sending the blank response to PayPal to verify, but since it is empty, you get `INVALID` back.

If you want to see what the IPN is posting to your listener, I recommend writing to an IPN log using `error_log()`.  This will show you what is happening when PayPal posts to your listener.

Additionally, I noticed a few things that originally messed me up.  First is the header info.  PayPal updated their system so that more header info is needed.  See [here](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=2891) for the notice about the update.  Basicall it is suggesting you change this:

```
$header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                  // HTTP POST request
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

to this:

```
$header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                  // HTTP POST request
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";              //<---added this
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";                     //<---and this
```

Last is that I had to add the `trim()` function around `$res`, since I was getting `VERIFIED` with a trailing space.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. It really looked favorable, but in practice, these changes just weren't enough to get the script working.